# Simulating a vibrating string: is divergence avoidable?

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, physics

I am trying to simulate a Gaussian wave traveling down a 1-D string, with some wave velocity 1.0, until it hits x=0, where the string changes to have a wave velocity 0.5.

My code currently is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Parameters
N = 301
x_max = 10.0
x_min = -x_max

v_left = 1.0
v_right = 0.5

t0 = -6.0
dt = 0.02

# Initial conditions
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)
v = (x < 0) * v_left + (x >= 0) * v_right
y = np.exp(-(x - v_left * t0) ** 2)
dy_dt = y * 2 * (x - v_left * t0) * v_left

dx = x[1] - x[0]

# Prepare for iteration
fig = plt.figure()
d2y_dx2 = np.zeros_like(x)
t = t0
iteration = 0

# Iterate
while t <= 4.0:
    # Approximate wave equation: d^2/dt^2 y = v^2 * d^2/dx^2
    d2y_dx2[1:-1] = np.diff(y, 2) / dx**2
    d2y_dt2 = v**2 * d2y_dx2
    
    y += dt * dy_dt + 0.5 * dt**2 * d2y_dt2
    dy_dt += dt * d2y_dt2
    
    # Check if we should plot
    for test_t in [-4.0, -2.0, -0.5, 0.5, 2.0, 4.0]:
        if abs(t - test_t) < (0.1 * dt):
            plt.plot(x, y, label=f"t={t}")
    
    # Prepare for next iteration
    iteration += 1
    t = t0 + (iteration * dt)

# Adjust plot
plt.xlim(-5.0, 5.0)
plt.ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
plt.plot([0.0, 0.0], [-1.1, 1.1], color="black")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

This algorithm works fine for some time, but it eventually turns crazy. The plot that is generated displays the state of the string at various points in time, and looks like so:
[image: Resulting graph]

My first instinct is that I'm simulating too crudely, but if I increase the density on the x-axis, or decrease `dt` then the craziness shows up *earlier*. Is this all just an artefact of the limitations of floats? How can I avoid this from happening? If I can't: how can I maximise the x/t density without before this happens?

Comment: Looks like you might have rediscovered [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), not sure if this is due to the precision, but slightly changing the input triggers the behavior, try `x_max = 12` or `x_max = 11` or `x_max = 10.5`

Comment: What boundary conditions are you trying to impose?

Comment: It's also important to note that you're using a down-winded scheme when you should be up-winding according to the wave motion. Down-winding the wave will lead to incorrect solutions, and is possibly the cause of your issue.

Comment: I get reasonable results if I change the lines updating `y` and `dy_dt` to this: `dy_dt += dt * d2y_dt2; y += dt * dy_dt`

Comment: See [the finite difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) and [Scikit-fdiff](https://scikit-fdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

Comment: @jared I'm not familiar with the terms "down-winded" and "up-winding", and google returns unrelated things. Do you have a link where I can read about these?

Comment: @NickODell That does indeed seem to work! But... Why? Effectively, we're just removing the factor of 0.5 from my formula `y += dt * dy_dt + 0.5 * dt**2 * d2y_dt2` but that 0.5 very much seems sensible to me. Is this because there should be higher-order terms that all just so happen to add up to the Taylor expansion of the original?

Comment: @acdr See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @acdr Sorry, if I knew why it worked I'd have written an answer. :P